# Make font size relative to the container it is in? Within StreamElements

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, font-size

I am helping my friend out with creating a custom alert for his Twitch stream. I have encountered one problem, the font size. While it works for most names, longer ones go off the alert and makes it look unprofessional.

Is there a way using HTML, CSS, JS or Jquery (without downloads) that allows me to make the font shrink based on its character length or its overall width?

Thanks

Comment: You can do that - have a look at [link](https://codepen.io/MadeByMike/pen/YPJJYv?editors=110) and [link](https://www.madebymike.com.au/writing/precise-control-responsive-typography/).  Change the width of your browser on the first one and watch the page header font change size

Comment: perhaps you should consider adding some code snippets or link to code on codesandbox or something.

Answer (score 0):

Considering an H1 with id of 'alert' (You can use anything else logic remains same)

```js
const alert = document.getElementById("alert");
const name = document.getElementById("alert").innerText;
    if (name.length < 15){
        alert.style.fontSize = "2em"; // Change these values accordingly
    } else {
        alert.style.fontSize = "0.5em";
    }
```

```html
<h1 id="alert">Some veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrryyyy long name</h1>
```

**Explanation:**
We get the name from the alert check if its length is less than some amount (here 15) and set it's font size to large else we keep it small.
Same thing can be applied in JQUERY using $(element).css()

Comment: Perhaps you could use `innerText` instead?
Or, the "new" `textContent`...